# Update Database After shell_exec() Using FFMPEG/Laravel

Tags: php, linux, bash, laravel, ffmpeg

I want to update a database record (MySQL) after the FFMPEG process is complete. Normally I would just call a function just after the FFMPEG command, but I needed to add `> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &` so I didn't have to wait for the FFMPEG process to complete which would mean the REST call would hang for a LONG time and that would cause bad UX for the front-end.

I'm not sure where to begin with it. My first thought is to make a REST request, but maybe calling the method in Laravel directly would be better.

Can I do a curl call after the FFMPEG command? Or can I call a PHP method? Or is there a better way?

PHP FFMPEG Method

```
private function transcode($movie)
{
    try {
        $name       = 'master.' . $movie->extension;
        $this->path = storage_path('app/public/movies/') . $movie->id . '/';
        $fps        = $this->getFrameRate($name);
        $width      = $this->getVideoWidth($name);
        $height     = $this->getVideoHeight($name);

        // ffmpeg commands
        $c = $this->buildCommand($width, $height, $fps);

        // ffmpeg -  added '> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &' so it will not wait to finish
        $ffmpeg = shell_exec('ffmpeg -i ' . $this->path . $name . ' -progress ' . $this->path . 'transcode.log' . $c . ' > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');

        return response()->json(['message' => 'transcode initiated'], 200); 

    }
    catch(\Exception $e)
    {
        return response()->json(['error' => $e->getMessage()], 500);
    }
}
```

Here is the bash curl post idea

```
$curl = 'curl --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://hostname/transcode/complete';

$ffmpeg = shell_exec('ffmpeg -i ' . $this->path . $name . ' -progress ' . $this->path . 'transcode.log' . $c . '; $curl > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
```

I could be going down the wrong path with the above, but I'm trying to move forward with something.

Comment: I got something that actually works. I created a shell script transcode.sh which I wrote all the transcoding for. I created a function in the .sh file that updates mysql with the data I need. Not sure it's the best way, but it does work pretty good.

Comment: Then I call the .sh file via `shell_exec(transcode.sh transcode path_to_video > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &)`

Answer (score 0):

Run your `ffmpeg` CLI command like so:

```sh
$ nohup $FFMPEG_COMMAND >> $LOG_FILE 2>&1 & echo $! > $PID_FILE
```

Then, check that the PID stored in $PID_FILE is actually running with:

```sh
FFMPEG_PID=`cat $PID_FILE 2>/dev/null`
if  kill -0 $FFMPEG_PID 2>/dev/null ;then
   # still running, do whatever you need to do
else
   # stopped running, do what needs doing
fi
```

You can also get the last output FFmpeg wrote with:

```sh
tail -1 $LOG_FILE
```